# How add output detail into test output from a Helm test?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created a Helm test but when it succeeds or fails, it only outputs a simple message about whether it succeeded or failed *(see below)*. I would like for it to be able to output custom info about what tests it ran and some info about them. So if it failed, I'd see which things failed specifically. And even if it succeeds, it would show me what things it tested.

```
NAME: my-app
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Jan 28 17:45:51 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 2
TEST SUITE:     my-app-test
Last Started:   Thu Jan 28 17:46:05 2021
Last Completed: Thu Jan 28 17:46:06 2021
Phase:          Succeeded
```

I don't see anywhere I can specify this or allow it to add to that output?

Comment: Hello, `$ helm test` has a parameter `--logs` where it's description states: "dump the logs from test pods (this runs after all tests are complete, but before any cleanup)". You could use that dump to give you messages more in line with your use case. Does this is something that you are looking for?

Comment: @DawidKruk It's not exactly what I wanted, but I can make that work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comment:

> Hello, `$ helm test` has a parameter `--logs` where it's description states: "dump the logs from test pods (this runs after all tests are complete, but before any cleanup)".

`helm test RELEASE_NAME --logs` can be used to produce logs from your scheduled tests:

- *[Helm.sh: Docs: Topic: Chart test](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_tests/)*

---

An example of how `$ helm test` works could be following:

- Create an example `Helm` Chart:

  - `$ helm create raven`
- Go into directory and install the Chart:

  - `$ cd raven && helm install raven .`
- After the Chart is deployed run:

  - `$ helm test raven`

The tests for this example Chart are located in the:

- `ROOT_CHART_DIR/templates/tests/`

The file that describes a test (`test-connection.yaml`) looks like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ include "raven.fullname" . }}-test-connection"
  labels:
    {{- include "raven.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: wget
      image: busybox
      command: ['wget']
      args: ['{{ include "raven.fullname" . }}:{{ .Values.service.port }}']
  restartPolicy: Never
```

This tests could be modified to output the specific messages depending on what the tests actually determined.

The output of the last command should be following:

```sh
NAME: raven
<-- OMITTED --> 
NOTES:
<-- OMITTED --> 

POD LOGS: raven-test-connection
Connecting to raven:80 (10.8.12.208:80)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |********************************|   612  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

As it can be seen above the output of `wget` command with its args was displayed.